# Lightweight server for ajax site on shared host?

Tags: javascript, django, webserver

Is there a lightweight webserver, especially on ram, someone can recommend for the purposes of using on a Shared Webhost?

Currently I'm using Django on [webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com/) and it eats up about 90MB of ram per an inactive site. I'm  thinking of doing more stuff on the client-side with the help of [js framework](http://sammyjs.org/), so I don't really need Django anymore. But I still may need db storage.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about switching to something like Flask (if you needed to whip up a quick, simple API) running on [ep.io](http://ep.io)?

Comment: That seems great, but the load time on the website is not very promising. Also, they are still in invite-only mode.